# OpenCV: not authorized to capture video OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize

Tags: xcode, opencv, camera

```
OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...
OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!
```

I am using macOS Mojave

in system preferences->security-> camera there is no terminal option appeared in this area.
how may I invoke terminal to access the camera,
is there any command that I can use?

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Run the same code from the command line. It will ask for camera permission and let you use your app on second run